# Make changes to a mounted volume from inside Docker container appear as if performed by a regular user while also keeping root privileges

Tags: linux, permissions, users, docker, privileges

If I use the [`--user`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user) argument of `docker run`, changes (like a simple `mkdir` for example) will appear as if performed by that (non-root) user. However, I won't be able to run commands like `apt` inside the container then, because they require root privileges. By default, there is no pre-installed `sudo` in `debian` or `ubuntu` Docker images.

What's an elegant way to overcome this issue?

Comment: I will also post an answer below, which has worked for me so far. Unfortunately this doesn't work for all cases.

Comment: I think this manual page will help https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/

Answer (score 0):

If you know *when* and *where* the changes will be written, you could just use `chown` on those files afterwards:

- Pass user and group ID (`id -u`, `id -g`) of the host (non-root) user to the Docker container with the `--env` argument
- Run your commands/script (inside the container) as root
- Finally, run `chown` (also still inside the container) to make the changes look like they've been performed by the host user

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, this is a particularly elegant solution, but it's possible to create a dummy user inside the container whose user and group ID match those of the (non-root) host user:

- Pass user and group ID (`id -u`, `id -g`) of the host (non-root) user to the Docker container with the `--env` argument
- Create a new group matching the group ID of the host (non-root) user

  ```
  addgroup --gid $DUMMY_GID dummy
  ```
- Create a new user matching the user ID of the host (non-root) user

  ```
  adduser --uid $DUMMY_UID --gid $DUMMY_GID --disabled-password --gecos "" dummy
  ```
- Commands which require root privileges will work
- Run your other commands/script with `runuser`

  ```
  runuser -u dummy -- command
  ```